# Accidentally merged remote branch to local master. How do I back out?

Tags: git

I did a bunch of work on a local master that I decided needed a new branch.
I created a branch `diffraction` on a machine at work and pushed it:

```
$ git checkout -b diffraction
$ git push
```

Then I went to another machine and fetched:

```
$ git fetch
...
 * [new branch]      diffraction -> origin/diffraction
...
$ git merge origin/master
Already up-to-date.
$ git merge origin/diffraction
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 .gitignore               |    4 +-
 Makefile                 |   11 +
...
 9 files changed, 8225 insertions(+), 24 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 
...
$ git branch
  atmosphere
* master
  rollback
```

No `diffraction` branch.  Plus I just pulled the origin/diffraction stuff into local master instead of getting a new branch and being checked out in it.  I thought that was dome automatically.

1. How do I back out changes (committed but not pushed) from my local master?  I want it to stay pointed at origin/master.
2. How I fetch origin/diffraction into a local diffraction?  Might be nice to have it automatically pointed there.

Comment: If you merged diffraction to your local master and you didn't want to do it just run `git reset HEAD^ --hard` while being checkedout on your local master branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you did `git merge origin/diffraction` you told Git to merge 'origin/diffraction' into your current branch. What you wanted instead was to tell Git to create a new local branch based on 'origin/diffraction'.

This is done with `git checkout -b diffraction origin/diffraction`, or even simpler:

```
git checkout diffraction
```

If you want to undo the merge you did by mistake, you can do:

```
git reset --hard @^
```

Which will reset the pointer of the current master branch, to the previous commit, you might want to check that the previous commit is the one you want, with `git show @^`. Otherwise you would need to replace '@^' with the SHA-1 of the commit you want to reset to.

Answer (score 1):

The setup

```
git clone https://github.com/svnpenn2/foo foo-1
git clone https://github.com/svnpenn2/foo foo-2
cd foo-1
set $RANDOM
echo $1 > README.md
git commit -am $1
git checkout -b diffraction
git push origin diffraction
cd ../foo-2
git fetch
git merge origin/diffraction
```

The problem

```
$ git branch
* master
```

The solution

```
$ git checkout diffraction
Branch diffraction set up to track remote branch diffraction from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'diffraction'

$ git branch
* diffraction
  master
```